# AWS Amplify Console issue while connecting GitLab Repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, aws-amplify

We have issue what appeared today. While i'm truing to Connect App using or Connect new branch using Gitlab Repository service throws alert like : "There was an issue connecting to your repository provider. Click the refresh button or try reloading the browser. If the error persists, it's likely that you have reached an API rate limit with your repository provider, wait an hour, and try again. If that still doesn’t work, email aws-amplify-customer@amazon.com ."

1. I have tested different OS / different Browser / different network  while accessing amplify console to connect repo.
2. Tested using new Gitlab account and also with new IAM user from our AWS account and from my personal AWS account
   Result's are same.

Comment: I experienced the same issue today, the same behavior and the same error message. Seems to be a blocked call which requests the gitlab projects (
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?membership=true&order_by=last_activity_at&per_page=100&page=1) with the error message *The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.*

Comment: Did it resolved on your side @LeifMarcus? i have rise support ticket but response will be tomorrow or next week.

Comment: also test GitHub and it works well, without issue

Comment: So far I have no solution for that. Ill add it, when I did find a solution ;)

Comment: Today amplify works well, without issue

Comment: Gitlab fixed an issue that caused the error: https://status.gitlab.com/pages/incident/5b36dc6502d06804c08349f7/5f47dfc5b0697104bd57839a